# SQL Where do I put Option Recompile?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've experiencing a strange thing where running my query takes one second, then pressing f5 again without changing a single thing now makes the exact same query take 10 seconds. And it would keep alternating. First run was instant, next run was slow, next run was instant and so on.

I think this might be a query plan thing so I want to add OPTION (RECOMPILE) to my query but I am not sure where to put it. Did I put it in the right place? This query will eventually be a stored procedure, I'm just doing things this way for now since it is easier to test.

```
DECLARE @LocalCompanyCode VARCHAR(5)
SET @LocalCompanyCode = '03'

DECLARE @LocalDivisionCode VARCHAR(5)
SET @LocalDivisionCode = '001'

DECLARE @LocalFromDate DATETIME
SET @LocalFromDate = '1/1/2018'

DECLARE @LocalToDate DATETIME
SET @LocalToDate = '9/1/2019'

DECLARE @LocalDetailLevel VARCHAR(50)
SET @LocalDetailLevel = 'color'

DECLARE @LocalOrderBy VARCHAR(50)
SET @LocalOrderBy = 'ordered'


IF @LocalDetailLevel = 'master'
BEGIN

    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT

        Master_Item
        ,'--' Item_Number
        ,'--' Color_Code 
        ,Description
        ,'--' Color_Description

        ,SUM(Unit_Retail) Sum_Unit_Retail
        ,AVG(Unit_Retail)  Avg_Unit_Retail

        ,SUM(Unit_MarkDown)  Sum_Unit_MarkDown
        ,AVG(Unit_MarkDown)  Avg_Unit_MarkDown
        ,AVG(Unit_MarkDown_Percent)  Avg_Unit_MarkDown_Percent

        ,SUM(Sell_Price)  Sum_Sell_Price
        ,AVG(Sell_Price)  Avg_Sell_Price

        ,SUM(Discount_Value)  Sum_Discount_Value
        ,AVG(Discount_Value)  Avg_Discount_Value
        ,AVG(Unit_Discount_Value_Percent)  Avg_Discount_Value_Percent

        ,SUM(Sale_Price)  Sum_Sale_Price
        ,AVG(Sale_Price)  Avg_Sale_Price

        ,SUM(Royalty_Cost)  Sum_Royalty_Cost
        ,AVG(Royalty_Cost)  Avg_Royalty_Cost
        ,AVG(Unit_Royalty_Cost_Percent)  Avg_Royalty_Cost_Percent

        ,SUM(Item_Cost)  Sum_Item_Cost
        ,AVG(Item_Cost)  Avg_Item_Cost
        ,AVG(Unit_Item_Cost_Percent)  Avg_Item_Cost_Percent

        ,SUM(Order_Gross_Profit_Minus_Discounts_And_Royalty_And_Freight)  Sum_Order_Gross_Profit_Minus_Discounts_And_Royalty_And_Freight
        ,AVG(Order_Gross_Profit_Minus_Discounts_And_Royalty_And_Freight)  Avg_Order_Gross_Profit_Minus_Discounts_And_Royalty_And_Freight
        ,AVG(Order_Gross_Profit_Minus_Discounts_And_Royalty_And_Freight_Percent)  Avg_Order_Gross_Profit_Minus_Discounts_And_Royalty_And_Freight_Percent

        ,MAX(Quantity_Invoiced+Quantity_Allocated)  Max_Quantity

        ,SUM(Quantity_Invoiced+Quantity_Allocated)  Total_Units

        ,COUNT(DISTINCT Customer_Purchase_Order_Number ) Total_Orders_Cont
        ,-1 Percent_Of_Orders_Cont

        ,SUM(Quantity_Invoiced+Quantity_Allocated) / COUNT(DISTINCT Customer_Purchase_Order_Number) Average_Order_Quantity

        ,SUM(Quantity_Returned)  Total_Units_Returned
        ,MAX(Quantity_Returned)  Max_Quantity_Returned
        ,SUM(Quantity_Returned)  
        /NULLIF(SUM(Quantity_Invoiced+Quantity_Allocated) ,0) Return_Percentage

        ,SUM(CASE WHEN F.Line_Status = 'CANCELLED' THEN Quantity_Ordered ELSE 0 END)  Cancelled_Count
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN F.Line_Status = 'CANCELLED' THEN Quantity_Ordered ELSE 0 END)  
        / NULLIF(SUM(Quantity_Ordered) ,0) Cancelled_Count_Percent

        ,SUM(CASE WHEN (Tags not like '%customerrequested_cancel%' and Tags not like '%ia_cancel%' and (FulfillmentState like 'partial%' or FinancialState like 'partial%')) THEN Short_Shipped ELSE 0 END)  Short_Shipped_Count
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN (Tags not like '%customerrequested_cancel%' and Tags not like '%ia_cancel%' and (FulfillmentState like 'partial%' or FinancialState like 'partial%')) THEN Short_Shipped ELSE 0 END)  
        / NULLIF(SUM(Quantity_Ordered) ,0) Short_Shipped_Count_Percent

    FROM 
        FinalEcomTable F

    WHERE
        1=1
        AND (F.Company_Code = @LocalCompanyCode OR @LocalCompanyCode IS NULL)  
        AND (F.Division_Code = @LocalDivisionCode OR @LocalDivisionCode IS NULL)
        AND F.Coal_Date BETWEEN @LocalFromDate AND DATEADD(dayofyear, 1, @LocalToDate)

    GROUP BY Master_Item, Item_Number, Color_Code, Description, Color_Description


    ) T

    ORDER BY  
        CASE WHEN @LocalOrderBy = 'ordered' THEN Total_Units END DESC, 
        CASE WHEN @LocalOrderBy = 'returned' THEN Total_Units_Returned END DESC,
        CASE WHEN @LocalOrderBy = 'cancelled' THEN Cancelled_Count END DESC,
        CASE WHEN @LocalOrderBy = 'shortshipped' THEN Short_Shipped_Count END DESC

 --------------------------------------------I put it here--------------------      
    OPTION  (RECOMPILE)

END

IF @LocalDetailLevel = 'size'
BEGIN

    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT

        Master_Item
        ,Item_Number
        ,'--' Color_Code 
        ,Description
        ,'--' Color_Description
        ,SUM(Unit_Retail)  Sum_Unit_Retail
        ,AVG(Unit_Retail)  Avg_Unit_Retail

        ,SUM(Unit_MarkDown)  Sum_Unit_MarkDown
        ,AVG(Unit_MarkDown)  Avg_Unit_MarkDown
        ,AVG(Unit_MarkDown_Percent)  Avg_Unit_MarkDown_Percent

        ,SUM(Sell_Price)  Sum_Sell_Price
        ,AVG(Sell_Price)  Avg_Sell_Price

        ,SUM(Discount_Value)  Sum_Discount_Value
        ,AVG(Discount_Value)  Avg_Discount_Value
        ,AVG(Unit_Discount_Value_Percent)  Avg_Discount_Value_Percent

        ,SUM(Sale_Price)  Sum_Sale_Price
        ,AVG(Sale_Price)  Avg_Sale_Price

        ,SUM(Royalty_Cost)  Sum_Royalty_Cost
        ,AVG(Royalty_Cost)  Avg_Royalty_Cost
        ,AVG(Unit_Royalty_Cost_Percent)  Avg_Royalty_Cost_Percent

        ,SUM(Item_Cost)  Sum_Item_Cost
        ,AVG(Item_Cost)  Avg_Item_Cost
        ,AVG(Unit_Item_Cost_Percent)  Avg_Item_Cost_Percent

        ,SUM(Order_Gross_Profit_Minus_Discounts_And_Royalty_And_Freight)  Sum_Order_Gross_Profit_Minus_Discounts_And_Royalty_And_Freight
        ,AVG(Order_Gross_Profit_Minus_Discounts_And_Royalty_And_Freight)  Avg_Order_Gross_Profit_Minus_Discounts_And_Royalty_And_Freight
        ,AVG(Order_Gross_Profit_Minus_Discounts_And_Royalty_And_Freight_Percent)  Avg_Order_Gross_Profit_Minus_Discounts_And_Royalty_And_Freight_Percent

        ,MAX(Quantity_Invoiced+Quantity_Allocated)  Max_Quantity

        ,SUM(Quantity_Invoiced+Quantity_Allocated)  Total_Units

        ,COUNT(DISTINCT Customer_Purchase_Order_Number) Total_Orders_Cont
        ,-1 Percent_Of_Orders_Cont

        ,SUM(Quantity_Invoiced+Quantity_Allocated) / COUNT(DISTINCT Customer_Purchase_Order_Number) Average_Order_Quantity

        ,SUM(Quantity_Returned)  Total_Units_Returned
        ,MAX(Quantity_Returned)  Max_Quantity_Returned
        ,SUM(Quantity_Returned)  
        /NULLIF(SUM(Quantity_Invoiced+Quantity_Allocated) ,0) Return_Percentage

        ,SUM(CASE WHEN F.Line_Status = 'CANCELLED' THEN Quantity_Ordered ELSE 0 END)  Cancelled_Count
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN F.Line_Status = 'CANCELLED' THEN Quantity_Ordered ELSE 0 END)  
        / NULLIF(SUM(Quantity_Ordered) ,0) Cancelled_Count_Percent

        ,SUM(CASE WHEN (Tags not like '%customerrequested_cancel%' and Tags not like '%ia_cancel%' and (FulfillmentState like 'partial%' or FinancialState like 'partial%')) THEN Short_Shipped ELSE 0 END)  Short_Shipped_Count
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN (Tags not like '%customerrequested_cancel%' and Tags not like '%ia_cancel%' and (FulfillmentState like 'partial%' or FinancialState like 'partial%')) THEN Short_Shipped ELSE 0 END)  
        / NULLIF(SUM(Quantity_Ordered) ,0) Short_Shipped_Count_Percent


    FROM 
        FinalEcomTable F

    WHERE
        1=1
        AND (F.Company_Code = @LocalCompanyCode OR @LocalCompanyCode IS NULL)  
        AND (F.Division_Code = @LocalDivisionCode OR @LocalDivisionCode IS NULL)
        AND F.Coal_Date BETWEEN @LocalFromDate AND DATEADD(dayofyear, 1, @LocalToDate)

    GROUP BY Master_Item, Item_Number, Color_Code, Description, Color_Description

    ) T

    ORDER BY  
        CASE WHEN @LocalOrderBy = 'ordered' THEN Total_Units END DESC, 
        CASE WHEN @LocalOrderBy = 'returned' THEN Total_Units_Returned END DESC,
        CASE WHEN @LocalOrderBy = 'cancelled' THEN Cancelled_Count END DESC,
        CASE WHEN @LocalOrderBy = 'shortshipped' THEN Short_Shipped_Count END DESC

    OPTION  (RECOMPILE)

END

IF @LocalDetailLevel = 'color'
BEGIN

    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT

        Master_Item
        ,Item_Number
        ,Color_Code 
        ,Description
        ,Color_Description
        ,SUM(Unit_Retail)  Sum_Unit_Retail
        ,AVG(Unit_Retail)  Avg_Unit_Retail

        ,SUM(Unit_MarkDown)  Sum_Unit_MarkDown
        ,AVG(Unit_MarkDown)  Avg_Unit_MarkDown
        ,AVG(Unit_MarkDown_Percent)  Avg_Unit_MarkDown_Percent

        ,SUM(Sell_Price)  Sum_Sell_Price
        ,AVG(Sell_Price)  Avg_Sell_Price

        ,SUM(Discount_Value)  Sum_Discount_Value
        ,AVG(Discount_Value)  Avg_Discount_Value
        ,AVG(Unit_Discount_Value_Percent)  Avg_Discount_Value_Percent

        ,SUM(Sale_Price)  Sum_Sale_Price
        ,AVG(Sale_Price)  Avg_Sale_Price

        ,SUM(Royalty_Cost)  Sum_Royalty_Cost
        ,AVG(Royalty_Cost)  Avg_Royalty_Cost
        ,AVG(Unit_Royalty_Cost_Percent)  Avg_Royalty_Cost_Percent

        ,SUM(Item_Cost)  Sum_Item_Cost
        ,AVG(Item_Cost)  Avg_Item_Cost
        ,AVG(Unit_Item_Cost_Percent)  Avg_Item_Cost_Percent

        ,SUM(Order_Gross_Profit_Minus_Discounts_And_Royalty_And_Freight)  Sum_Order_Gross_Profit_Minus_Discounts_And_Royalty_And_Freight
        ,AVG(Order_Gross_Profit_Minus_Discounts_And_Royalty_And_Freight)  Avg_Order_Gross_Profit_Minus_Discounts_And_Royalty_And_Freight
        ,AVG(Order_Gross_Profit_Minus_Discounts_And_Royalty_And_Freight_Percent)  Avg_Order_Gross_Profit_Minus_Discounts_And_Royalty_And_Freight_Percent

        ,MAX(Quantity_Invoiced+Quantity_Allocated)  Max_Quantity

        ,SUM(Quantity_Invoiced+Quantity_Allocated)  Total_Units

        ,COUNT(DISTINCT Customer_Purchase_Order_Number) Total_Orders_Cont
        ,-1 Percent_Of_Orders_Cont

        ,SUM(Quantity_Invoiced+Quantity_Allocated) / COUNT(DISTINCT Customer_Purchase_Order_Number) Average_Order_Quantity

        ,SUM(Quantity_Returned)  Total_Units_Returned
        ,MAX(Quantity_Returned)  Max_Quantity_Returned
        ,SUM(Quantity_Returned)  
        /NULLIF(SUM(Quantity_Invoiced+Quantity_Allocated) ,0) Return_Percentage

        ,SUM(CASE WHEN F.Line_Status = 'CANCELLED' THEN Quantity_Ordered ELSE 0 END)  Cancelled_Count
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN F.Line_Status = 'CANCELLED' THEN Quantity_Ordered ELSE 0 END)  
        / NULLIF(SUM(Quantity_Ordered) ,0) Cancelled_Count_Percent

        ,SUM(CASE WHEN (Tags not like '%customerrequested_cancel%' and Tags not like '%ia_cancel%' and (FulfillmentState like 'partial%' or FinancialState like 'partial%')) THEN Short_Shipped ELSE 0 END)  Short_Shipped_Count
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN (Tags not like '%customerrequested_cancel%' and Tags not like '%ia_cancel%' and (FulfillmentState like 'partial%' or FinancialState like 'partial%')) THEN Short_Shipped ELSE 0 END)  
        / NULLIF(SUM(Quantity_Ordered) ,0) Short_Shipped_Count_Percent

    FROM 
        FinalEcomTable F

    WHERE
        1=1
        AND (F.Company_Code = @LocalCompanyCode OR @LocalCompanyCode IS NULL)  
        AND (F.Division_Code = @LocalDivisionCode OR @LocalDivisionCode IS NULL)
        AND F.Coal_Date BETWEEN @LocalFromDate AND DATEADD(dayofyear, 1, @LocalToDate)

    GROUP BY Master_Item, Item_Number, Color_Code, Description, Color_Description

    ) T

    ORDER BY  
        CASE WHEN @LocalOrderBy = 'ordered' THEN Total_Units END DESC, 
        CASE WHEN @LocalOrderBy = 'returned' THEN Total_Units_Returned END DESC,
        CASE WHEN @LocalOrderBy = 'cancelled' THEN Cancelled_Count END DESC,
        CASE WHEN @LocalOrderBy = 'shortshipped' THEN Short_Shipped_Count END DESC

    OPTION  (RECOMPILE)

END
```

Comment: Please read the [reference docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/option-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's where you put it if you want to just recompile that statement each time.

If this code is part of a proc and you want to recompile the whole proc each time, you do that by adding WITH RECOMPILE to the procedure definition.

Comment: Where would I put the "WITH RECOMILE" in a stored procedure? In the part where I declare the parameters or where the actual stuff happens. Becouse I want to set some parameters and then recompile the whole SP.